# How to replicate listview as seen in the "Start" menu

Tags: wear-os

I would like to implement a list view as seen below. [image]

Apparently this is a WearableListView with a CircledImageView. However I cannot seem to find which function allows me to determine the middle view. I also want to be able to do the "size up" animation on the new one and a "size down" on the old selected one... Right now I tried a basic onscroll but no cigar.

```
     mListView.addOnScrollListener(new WearableListView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScroll(int i) {
                    Log.d("Recycler","Scroll: "+i);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAbsoluteScrollChange(int i) {
                    Log.d("Recycler","ABsScrollChange: "+i);
                }

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(int i) {
                    Log.d("Recycler","ScrollState: "+i);
                }


                @Override
                public void onCentralPositionChanged(int i) {
                    Log.d("Recycler","Center: "+i);
                }

            });
```

**EDIT:** Okay so I now know how to find the center view. But I was wondering if anyone figured out how to retrive the current view so that I can modify the current selected view.

**EDIT 2** Okay now I can modify the selected view. Still don't know hot to properly remove properties after an object is deselected however..

Comment: I want to implement the same. Would you like to share some of your code here.

Comment: I have created an example and have written a post on the same: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-wear-part-5-wearablelistview/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to implement getProximityMinValue() and getProximityMaxValue() in your WearableListView.Item subclass:

```
private final class MyItemView extends FrameLayout implements WearableListView.Item {

  final CircledImageView image;
  final TextView text;

  public MyItemView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    View.inflate(context, R.layout.wearablelistview_item, this);
    image = (CircledImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
  }

  @Override
  public float getProximityMinValue() {
    return mDefaultCircleRadius;
  }

  @Override
  public float getProximityMaxValue() {
    return mSelectedCircleRadius;
  }

  @Override
  public float getCurrentProximityValue() {
    return image.getCircleRadius();
  }

  @Override
  public void setScalingAnimatorValue(float value) {
    image.setCircleRadius(value);
    image.setCircleRadiusPressed(value);
  }

  @Override
  public void onScaleUpStart() {
    image.setAlpha(1f);
    text.setAlpha(1f);
  }

  @Override
  public void onScaleDownStart() {
    image.setAlpha(0.5f);
    text.setAlpha(0.5f);
  }
}
```

Full working example [source code here](https://github.com/peterfriese/AndroidWear/tree/master/WearableListViewSample).

Comment: This still does not solve the issue of having a HEAD space or title bar on the list similar to what Google does on settings for Wear. Any suggestions? I say issue because many asked for how it is done and no one came with an answer

Comment: @maheshren try `\...\sdk\samples\android-20\wearable\Timer`

Answer (score 2):

It is way easier than the answers given here. Just use `onCenterPosition` and `onNonCenterPosition` like this:

```
public class WearableListItemLayout extends LinearLayout implements WearableListView.OnCenterProximityListener {

    private ImageView mCircle;
    private TextView mName;

    private final float mFadedTextAlpha;
    private final int mFadedCircleColor;
    private final int mChosenCircleColor;

    public WearableListItemLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public WearableListItemLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public WearableListItemLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                  int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        mFadedTextAlpha = 200f / 100f;
        mFadedCircleColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.grey);
        mChosenCircleColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
    }

    // Get references to the icon and text in the item layout definition
    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        // These are defined in the layout file for list items
        // (see next section)
        mCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle);
        mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCenterPosition(boolean animate) {
        mName.setAlpha(1f);
        ((GradientDrawable) mCircle.getDrawable()).setColor(mChosenCircleColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNonCenterPosition(boolean animate) {
        ((GradientDrawable) mCircle.getDrawable()).setColor(mFadedCircleColor);
        mName.setAlpha(mFadedTextAlpha);
    }
}
```

Note: This is for a listview which gets a colored circle when in the center, but it can be easily adjusted for what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking to display a title on top of my wearable list view.

I resolved this issue by adding a TextView element as part of my wearable list view layout. Also, it is recommended to set the app:layout_box to "left|bottom|right" to allow for a nicer list view when scrolling.

Here's my layout XML (notice the TextView element):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
 
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_box="left|bottom|right">
 
        <android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
            android:id="@+id/wearable_List"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#434343">
        </android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView>
 
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:fontFamily="courrier"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Settings"/>
 
    </ FrameLayout >
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

For further reading, you can also take a look at this example which explains things clearly:
http://www.learnandroidwear.com/sample-1